# How to get the path of image stored in sd card at 1st position android

Tags: android, image

I wan to get the path of image stored in first position in sd card android.How to get that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: What you have tried yet

Comment: Can you please explain in some more details ?

Comment: A little more context please. What do you mean by image? An Android image? A picture? Also what do you mean by "first position"? Please also add what you already did try (Add some code).

Comment: I have already got the path of images stored in external storage directory.List of images are in the particular file.I want to get the exact path of image in first position stored in sd card.

Comment: Do you mean you have a text file and basically want to get the first line?

Comment: No,I'm having set of images downloaded from server.I want to get the path of the first image.

Comment: Again: What do you mean by first? Show us some code you already have.

Comment: uhf..I'm having list of images stored in file in sd card.I want to view the image in first position from the list of images.

Comment: How does that list of images look like?

Comment: It in the folder called savedimages in sd card.The images are in the extension of .file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File imageFolder = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/savedimages");
if (imageFolder.isDirectory()) {
    FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.endsWith(".file");
            }
        };
    File firstFile = imageFolder.listFiles(filter)[0];
    String firstImagePath = firstFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: this is not working for me.imageFolder.listFiles(filter)[0] gives me null values.

Comment: @asliyanage this probably means that there are no files that match the specified filter in the folder